# How do I remove lines that contain characters other than the ones I specifiy?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a list that contains DNA and random lines like this:

```
 dnalist=['AGTCCTGCAGTCG', '@#$@#!AG!!ECG']
```

I want to make a function that filters out any lines that containing anything other than the characters 'A' 'G' 'C' or 'T'. So far my code has a very crude way of filtering that can easily be fooled:

```
def seperate(B):
    'takes a list and seperates the DNA lines'
    newlist=[]
    for i in B:
      if i[0]=='G'or i[0]=='A' or i[0]=='T' or i[0]=='C':
           newlist.append(i)           
    return newlist
```

If anyone can point me to some helpful tutorials regarding python data manipulation that would be great too. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly the best tool for data manipulation you can learn is comprehensions (check out the Python docs tutorial to learn about those). Here's a solution using them:

```
[string for string in dnalist if all(char in "GATC" for char in string)]
```

You can see you basically describe the data you want. The above means "give me all the strings where all of the characters in the string are in the set {"G", "A", "T", "C"}.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different and efficient ways to do it. This is one way:

```
In [1]: dnalist=['AGTCCTGCAGTCG', '@#$@#!AG!!ECG']

In [2]: filter(lambda x: set(x).issubset(set('ACGT')), dnalist)
Out[2]: ['AGTCCTGCAGTCG']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) with regex `[^AGTC]` which tries to find out non `AGTC` characters, if there is any in the string, exclude it with an `if` in the list comprehension:

```
import re
[x for x in dnalist if not re.search('[^AGTC]', x)]
# ['AGTCCTGCAGTCG']
```